# Windows: Configure your IP Tables to forward all traffic except HTTP traffic

Tags: windows, http, iptables, portforwarding

I want to redirect all incoming HTTP traffic to my localhost (Apache server).

One can do this on *nginx (Linux Distribution Operation System ) using 'iptables', i want to do this on windows 7.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be with the netsh command:

```
netsh firewall (deprecated after XP and 2003)
netsh advfirewall (Vista, 7, and 2008)
```